# sqlalchemy instance population

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I wonder when an sqlalchemy model instance is populated with database content when I use query methods like query.get or query.all.

Is it lazy loaded on these methods call, or the effective database query and instance population is done when I iterate over the query result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlalclemy` has query executors: `first()`, `get()`, `all()`, ... So when you call those methods on a query object it fetches data from database. After one of those method calls you will have data. When you looping, it iterate over already fetched data.

let's say you have `User` class:

```
query = session.query(User) #returns query object
query = query.filter(name=='John') #specified query criteria 
user = query.first() #now your user instance populated
print(user.name) #John
users = query.all() #a list of User instance, populated
```

With the last line, now you have a list of User instance which populated, can iterate over that list as follows:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.name, user.id)
```